# how to fix problem of my app (just show the view pager)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to write android app and that work's fine.
next I write code for view pager and after that my app just show 3 slide of view pager.
what's problem?

tell me how create viewpager for when I swipe the last slid just viewpager gone and app go on.

I want app start with view pager for some notes...and after that viewpager visible

here is Adapter

```
    public MypagerAdapter(String[] title, Context context,int[]color) {

        this.title = title;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
        this.color=color;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return title.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {

        return view == o;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, container, false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.pagertext);

        textView.setText(this.title[position]);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(color[position]);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;

    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }
```

and here is my main activity code here

```
  <RelativeLayoutenter 
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="Click to find" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

without view pager my app work fine.so I don't know what's problem?
my app button is in main activity  and have intent to go second activity but 
with view pager i haven't access to that.

sorry for my english

Comment: The `ViewPager` is covering the `Button`, and intercepting the touch events. If that `Button` is supposed to be at the top, then add `android:layout_below="@+id/button1"` to the `<ViewPager>`.

Comment: tell me how create viewpager for when I swipe the last slid just viewpager gone and app go on.

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewPager`'s height is set as `match_parent`. This is hiding the button.

Comment: tell me how create viewpager for when I swipe the last slid just viewpager gone and app go on.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand

Comment: I want app start with view pager for some notes...and after that viewpager visible